# Pandas: Set index of column before map operation which has duplicate values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframes which has ORDER_ID as the common column. I have to match EMP_ID for each ORDER_ID in df2. The same EMP_ID can be matched for several Orders.

**DF:**

```
    ORDER_ID    TYPE    EMP_ID
0   23991          A    9233
1   31106          A    2457
2   30062          A    2457
3   30062          A    1234
```

**DF2:**

```
    ORDER_ID    O_INFO  YEAR    PRICE
0   23991           OK  2011    100
1   31106           OK  2000    200
2   30062           OK  2000    300
```

**OUTPUT SHOULD BE:**
As one order will be attended by many employees, I would want to group and map all the employees who attended that order

```
    ORDER_ID    O_INFO  YEAR    PRICE   EMP_ID      
0   23991           OK  2011    100      9233
1   31106           OK  2000    200      2457
2   30062           OK  2000    300      2457,1234
```

I tried the map function as below:
    df  = df.set_index(‘ORDER_ID’)

```
df2 ['EMP'] = df2[‘ORDER_ID’].map(df[‘EMP_ID'])
```

I get the error: because values in the ORDER_ID are not unique to be set as index. But map function does not work without setting indexes. It returns NaN values without setting index.

```
InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

Performing merge does not map the EMP_ID for the ORDER but returns Nan values again

```
df.merge(df2, on='ORDER_ID', how='left')
```

Comment: If there are many employees per ORDER_ID, what would you want to be mapped in `df2`? The first? Random? Last?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ In df2, for each ORDER_ID, I have to map the EMP_ID who attended the ORDER

Comment: I understand that, but if there are multiple employees per order, who will you map?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ To group and map all the employees who attended that order

Comment: Wow... well, map isn't going to do it. It only maps one key to one value. By the way, these details are important, and they should be in your question.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Is there a function where we can group by EMP_ID and then map the values?

Comment: Sorry, I'd like to help, but I'm a bit busy. I think tarashypka's merge should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need aggregate `EMP_ID` by duplicates in `ORDER_ID` with `join` and then `map` working perfectly:

```
s = df1['EMP_ID'].astype(str).groupby(df1['ORDER_ID']).apply(', '.join)
print (s)
ORDER_ID
23991          9233
30062    2457, 2457
31106          2457
Name: EMP_ID, dtype: object

df2['EMP'] = df2['ORDER_ID'].map(s)
print (df2)
   ORDER_ID O_INFO  YEAR  PRICE         EMP
0     23991     OK  2011    100        9233
1     31106     OK  2000    200        2457
2     30062     OK  2000    300  2457, 2457
```

Comment: Perfect! `df1['EMP_ID'].astype(str).groupby(df1['ORDER_ID']).count()` gave the number of employees too.

Comment: You are welcome! If need count them it is same as `df1['EMP_ID'].groupby(df1['ORDER_ID']).count()` and `df1.groupby('ORDER_ID')['EMP_ID'].count()`